# Spring JSP : According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute path is mandatory for tag input

Tags: spring, jsp

When adding input tag (spring input comp) using javascript with ajax use. i got following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/configurationManagement.jsp (line: 27, column: 14) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute path is mandatory for tag input
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:237)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:858)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1798)
```

My Code to add input tag in div is.

```
var $col4div1 = $('<div class="form-group">');
$("<form:input />")
.attr("path","emailGatwayParameter["+ index + "].hostPortNumber")
.attr("id","emailParameterPort"+ index)
.attr("class","form-control")
.appendTo($col4div1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `<form:input />` which doesn't have a required path attribute. It should be like this: `<form:input path="someParamName" />`, and `"someParamName"` should match the property in your Spring form object for this form.

For more info please check [spring-form.tld](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input).